# Post files using request from the url file

Tags: python

This code works for me :

```
file = open('E:\Work\image-larger-api\static\images\other (1).png','rb')
print(file)
files = {'file': file}
response = scrape_trace_session.post(target_audience, files=files)
```

But I need to send file from the url without saving it to the files.

I did this  :

```
file= urlopen('https://storage.googleapis.com/dfgdfgfdgfdg/navigation-bottom/other.png')
```

But this is not working for me, can I parse HttpResponse to BufferReader  (what open does)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import requests

with requests.get('https://picsum.photos/200/300', stream=True, allow_redirects=True) as r:   # substitute your path here
    requests.post(' <upload url> ', files = {
        'file' : r.content
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to fetch a file from URL first, and then send it to another URL without saving it to the disk, right? In this case, you can do it as follows:

```
import requests


r = requests.get('https://example.com/download/image.jpg')

if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    requests.post('https://example.com/upload', files={'image': r.content})
```